# React firestore increment gives type error

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to increase a value of a number field in my firestore database when a button clicked. I've setup the onClick button, but when I click it gives me this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'increment' of undefined

I can't find what I did wrong.

Here is my code:

```
import React,{useState,useEffect, useRef, useContext} from 'react'
import UserContext from  './UserContext.js';
import fire from '../config/Fire';
import copper from '../img/coppernew.jpg'
function useTimes(){
  const user = useContext(UserContext)
  const [kullanici,setTimes] = useState([])
  useEffect(()=>{
    fire
      .firestore()
      .collection('kullanici')
      .doc(user)
      .onSnapshot((doc)=>{
          const newTimes = doc.data()
          setTimes(newTimes)
      })
  },[])

  return kullanici
}

function upgradecopper(){
  var userUid = fire.auth().currentUser.uid;
  console.log(userUid);
  var db = fire.firestore();
  var copperincrease =  db.collection("kullanici").doc(userUid);
  copperincrease.update({
    copper:fire.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)
  });
}
const Mine = () => {
    const kullanici =useTimes()
    return(
      <div className="mine">
        <div>
        <ul className="a">
        <ul className="dik2"><li><button onClick={()=>upgradecopper()}>Upgrade Copper Mine</button>(LVL: {kullanici.copper})</li><li><span><img src={copper} alt="copper"/></span></li></ul>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <li>Account: <span>{kullanici.email} </span></li>
      </div>
      )
    }

export default Mine
```

My Fire.js

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore'
import 'firebase/auth';



const config = { 
    (there is my api info)
};
const fire = firebase.initializeApp(config);
export default fire;
```

New Fire.js file:

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore'
import 'firebase/auth';



const config = { /* COPY THE ACTUAL CONFIG FROM FIREBASE CONSOLE */
    (there is my api info)
};
const fire = firebase.initializeApp(config);
export default fire;
```

Comment: What do you have in `Fire.js` or `Fire.ts`?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen added my Fire.js code also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're exporting the `FirebaseApp` instance. But `increment` is declared on the `FieldValue` constant.

So you'll need to also import `firebase` into the main file, and then use `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)` as shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#increment_a_numeric_value).

Comment: I imported firebase to my Fire.js file  (shown in the edit) but it didnt work until i imported firebase to my main file. May i ask why do i have to import in the same file? Why doesnt it take from Fire.js file?

Comment: You're not exporting the top-level `firebase` object from `Fire.js`, but are exporting a `FirebaseApp` instance. And a `FirebaseApp` doesn't have a `FieldValue` property. In other words: `firebase.firestore.FieldValue` is shared between all instances, while `firebase.firestore()` gets you a single instance.